# window.close() after page redirect

Tags: javascript, video, dom-events

I am on a work intranet only having to support IE8. I am creating a page called "watch video" which (as the name suggests) serves a video to the client. A page linking to a video will open this page in a popup with the link in the url. The person accessing the video (and a datetime stamp) is then logged into the database.

The page is just a simple "Your video will start momentarily, otherwise click here" with the click here having a href of `FILE:\\sharedDrive:\somePath\someVideo.wmv`. I then automatically open the video by running `document.getElementById('anchor').click()` to click the anchor. The video then opens in Windows Media Player and i then want to do `window.close()`.

But the page has changed to a blank page because I have clicked the anchor. Do you know how I could close the page after it has redirected? I am trying this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('watchVideo').click();
    self.close();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution that i found (inspired by [PualPRO's](/users/772035/paulpro) answer) was this

```
<a id="myAnchor" href="FILE:\\sharedDrive:\somePath\someVideo.wmv" target="myIframe" onclick="setTimeout(function(){window.close()}, 5000)">Watch Video</a>

<iframe name="myIframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>

<script>
    document.getElementById('myAnchor').click();
</script>
```

So then on load it automatically clicks the anchor to trigger then events. I put the `window.close()` inside a `setTimeout` so that the page had time to load the href before closing itself. Otherwise it would close before opening the file.

Answer (score 3):

Add `target="_blank"` to your `<a>` tag so that it opens in a new separate Window (Which the browser will automatically close before it is visible since it plays it in Windows Media Player). Then you can close the current window as well.

Comment: This has worked. Exploring other answers and avenues before i tick it.

Comment: I wish i could give you a tick. You helped me solve the answer. I just changed target="_blank" to target="myIframe" and it works. See my answer. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are doing this in IE or maybe firefox?

```
document.getElementById('anchor').onclick = "window.open('FILE:\\sharedDrive:\somePath\someVideo.wmv'); window.close()";
```

or instead of `window.close()` do a `return false;` that will let the page know not to do the default.

Comment: It says i am on an intranet with IE8. Will give it a go.

Comment: @timothy Whoops I missed that. But a `return false` or `window.close` should work.